# Better way to move to production?

Tags: openedge

We have recently set up a new development server for upgrading, progress, database and application.

We have tested everything and it works fine, but can we simply rename the server as 'production' and then develop a new development server again to save time?

I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: You really need to provide more information about your setup etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory yes.

Normally a client connecting to a Progress DB only needs to know server name/IP and port number...

But it sounds like a strange approach. Even if the dev server and the production server are similar types with same specification (discs, memory, cpu etc) righ now you cannot know that they always will be.

Bite the bullet and put down some work on this. It will be worth it in the long run.

What you need is some kind of process or policy on how to upgrade your development environment. Quite likely you need more of those, for instance:

- How do we do backups?
- How do we do restores?
- How do we do database changes?
- etc.

You can do this in a number of different ways you can but I've found that the absolutely best way (for us at least) is clever scripting.

Another option might be a a check list that a sys admin/DBA follows but then there's always the risk that something is skipped by mistake.

We mix the two approaches. When installing a new version of Progress, we do it manually with the use of check lists and check everything a couple of times before migrating our application and database. We do it in test environment first, of course.

Things done often (like schema changes, application upgrades etc) is better to script.

**An example checklist for installing Progress:**

- Make sure the server is not in production
- Make backups and store them safely
- Make sure you've filled in the "Pre-installation check list" provided by Progress
- Install/Upgrade Progress
- Compare settings (ubroker.properties etc)
- Change admin scripts to reflect possible new paths
- Test, test and test again

**What should the script look like?**

First of all when scripting it's always best to make "single atomic scripts". For instance you shouldn't need to run several scripts to upgrade your application.

Since you don't give us much info about your environment that's hard to say what the script should look like. What are you upgrading for instance? Progress or your database schema or your application?

All steps needs to be logged. That way you can compare errors with the script and see what steps didn't work.

**Very basic application upgrade script:**

- Backup existing files
- Copy new files from "ready" area, possibly only changed files
- Compile
- Restart appservers etc if needed.

That are some very basic steps. Different systems are, eh, different. Therefore it's hard for me to tell you how to do it...

**Of course you need to develop this script in a separate test environment! Don't mess with production!**

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

"Simply", of course depends on how simple your environment is.